# "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime." Error in Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha

Whenever i try to run the following command,

`./gradlew signingReport` 
I get the following error,

`The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.` 
(I'm a Mac User)

I keep getting this error, whenever i run the above-mentioned command, all i want are the SHA keys so that i can integrate OTP phone verification through Firebase Authentication into my Flutter App.

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-locate-a-java-runtime-error-when-building-for-android-on-mac/221148